# Java generic builder

Tags: java, generics, builder-pattern

Suppose I need some `DerivedBuilder` to extend some `BaseBuilder`. Base builder has some method like `foo` (which returns `BaseBuilder`). Derived builder has method `bar`. Method `bar` should be invoked after method `foo`. In order to do it I can override `foo` method in `DerivedBuilder` like this:

```
@Override
public DerivedBuilder foo() {
    super.foo();
    return this;
}
```

The problem is that `BaseBuilder` has a lot of methods like `foo` and I have to override each one of them. I don't want to do that so I tried to use generics:

```
public class BaseBuilder<T extends BaseBuilder> {
    ...

    public T foo() {
        ...
        return (T)this;
    }
}

public class DerivedBuilder<T extends DerivedBuilder> extends BaseBuilder<T> {
    public T bar() {
        ...
        return (T)this;
    }
}
```

But the problem is that I still can not write

```
new DerivedBuilder<DerivedBuilder>()
        .foo()
        .bar()
```

Even though `T` here is `DerivedBuilder`. What can I do in order to not to override a lot of functions?

Comment: With this approch of generics, you can call : `new DerivedBuilder<DerivedBuilder>().foo().bar()`. It will work and execute `foo` first and then `bar`. If you want to call more methods of `BaseBuilder` and lastly you want to call `DerivedBuilder` method, then it's not possible, because second time, method returns reference of `BaseBuilder`, with this you can't call `DerivedBuilder`'s method.

Comment: @Sandeep.K I tried to execute that and compiler complains that `bar` was not defined in `BaseBuilder` because then I do `.foo().bar()` the only thing compiler knows about `T` after executing `foo` is that this `T` extends `BaseBuilder`

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217013/how-to-force-derived-class-to-call-super-method-like-android-does) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853638/require-override-of-method-to-call-super) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142460/how-do-i-force-a-polymorphic-call-to-the-super-method)...

Comment: @user1803551 I don't see how this solves my problem. In your links described some ways to ensure that super method was called when my question is about how not to call it explicitly.

Comment: They address the same problem and (some of) the answers there answer your question. There is no contradiction between "some ways to ensure that super method was called" and "how not to call it explicitly" - ensuring it's called can, in some way, be done not explicitly, which is what the answers there show.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is the definition of `DerivedBuilder`:

```
class DerivedBuilder<T extends DerivedBuilder>;
```

And then instantiating it with a type erased argument `new DerivedBuilder<DerivedBuilder<...what?...>>()`.

You'll need a fully defined derived type, like this:

```
public class BaseBuilder<T extends BaseBuilder<T>> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T foo() {
        return (T)this;
    }
}

public class DerivedBuilder extends BaseBuilder<DerivedBuilder> {
    public DerivedBuilder bar() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Check [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/o8W5gg).

Comment: Is there also a possibility to derive the `DerivedBuilder` further, for example `SubDerivedBuilder`? `SubDerivedBuilderM<...> extends DerivedBuilder<...>`

Comment: @MCEmperor yes, but you need to make all the most derived types pass complete types to their base class. Check [this fork](http://ideone.com/ZIAuqs)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [BeyelerStudios's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39018348/507738), if you want to nest further, you can just use this:

```
class Base<T extends Base<?>> {
    public T alpha() { return (T) this; }
    public T bravo() { return (T) this; }
    public T foxtrot() { return (T) this; }
}

class Derived<T extends Derived<?>> extends Base<T> {
    public T charlie() { return (T) this; }
    public T golf() { return (T) this; }
}

class FurtherDerived<T extends FurtherDerived<?>> extends Derived<T> {
    public T delta() { return (T) this; }
    public T hotel() { return (T) this; }
}

class MuchFurtherDerived<T extends MuchFurtherDerived<?>> extends FurtherDerived<T> {
    public T echo() { return (T) this; }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MuchFurtherDerived<MuchFurtherDerived<?>>()
        .alpha().bravo().charlie().delta().echo().foxtrot().golf().hotel()
        .bravo().golf().delta().delta().delta().hotel().alpha().echo()
        .echo().alpha().hotel().foxtrot();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of casting `return (T) this;` I here did a `Class.cast(this)`.

To realize:

```
BaseBuilder.build(ExtendedBuilder.class).foo().bar().foo().bar();
```

Every class in the hierarch needs to know the actual final child class, hence I chose to make a *factory method* `build` in the base class.

The cast of `this` to the actual child is done in a final method of the base class too, providing `return me();`.

```
class BaseBuilder<B extends BaseBuilder<B>> {

    protected Class<B> type;

    public static <T extends BaseBuilder<T>> T build(Class<T> type) {
        try {
            T b = type.newInstance();
            b.type = type;
            return b;
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    protected final B me() {
        return type.cast(this);
    }

    B foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
        return me();
    }
}

class ExtendedBuilder extends BaseBuilder<ExtendedBuilder> {

    ExtendedBuilder bar() {
        System.out.println("bar");
        return me();
    }
}
```

Comment: And now you have a Builder Factory. Also, the `type` field and the `type.cast(this)` is pointless, because it doesn't provide any additional compile-time safety and complicates the entire thing.

Comment: @XetraSu proposed `static class` which probably fits the usage of them.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that the method foo() should be executed before method bar().
If that is correct, you can apply the Template Design Pattern.
Create a abstract method bar in the BaseBuilder.
And a new method say 'template'. The method template will define the sequence- first foo() is executed followed by bar().
DerivedBuilder will provide the implementation for the method bar.

```
public abstract class BaseBuilder {

    public void foo(){
        System.out.println("foo");
    }

    public abstract void bar();

    public void template(){
        foo();
        bar();
    }
}

public class DerivedBuilder extends BaseBuilder{

    @Override
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("bar");      
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseBuilder builder = new DerivedBuilder();
        builder.template();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.