# How did Android implement the checks for SuperNotCalledException?

Tags: android, oop, inheritance, super, android-lifecycle

In the `Activity` class, Android provides runtime enforcement that `super()` [must be called](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) for overridden lifecycle callback methods. If you forget do do so, it throws SuperNotCalledException.

Exactly how was this implemented specifically on Android?  Please point me to the actual source implementation if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they [clear a flag in the super methods and check that it was set](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/app/Activity.java#3488):

```
final void performStart() {
    mCalled = false;
    mInstrumentation.callActivityOnStart(this);
    if (!mCalled) {
        throw new SuperNotCalledException(
            "Activity " + mComponent.toShortString() +
            " did not call through to super.onStart()");
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if this is why calling the wrong super.x method doesn't cause the app to crash? I'm not sure if this was fixed but previously you could call super.onResume in onStart and it wouldn't throw that exception...

Comment: It makes sense; there's only one flag.  Since this is intended to prevent people from forgetting to call `super()` I can't imagine someone would call another `super()` method inadvertently.

Answer (score 0):

As a side-note android just announced a new annotation, @CallSuper that drops you a warning whenever the super is not called for the @CallSuper annotated method when it gets overidden.

More details:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations